# What is the j2me datatype suited to upload a j2me image to a PHP file?

Tags: php, java-me, lwuit

I want to upload LWUIT images from a java j2me application to a webserver. So I thought about webservice and php files. So I wonder what datatype should I send to the php file in order to transform this datatype to get an image ? And how should I process the datatype in the php file in order to get an image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the answer is Multipart Request. I haven't done this with JavaME and moreover, I haven't done this with php. But [here is a tutorial](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/HTTP_Post_multipart_file_upload_in_Java_ME) to send that kind of request from Java ME.

Maybe someone can add something about php, which is not my strength.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The better data type for image is byte array.